# How to link a PDF Document to a Record using Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, pdf, datagrid, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm Stuck the following problem: How can I link a PDF Document to a Record in a Data Grid using Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 and Visual Basic?

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest you make your question more specific - we need to know what you mean by "link." If you have a URI or path to a PDF in one of your fields, that could be called a link, but I have a feeling that you want more than that. Do you want the user to open the file with a single click in the grid? Do you want to be able to browse to the file? If you can tell us exactly what you want, there is probably a way to make it happen.

Comment: I would like for the link to point to a location on the server so that if the user was to click the link it would open up the PDF. It would be really awesome I could just highlight the row of the product and then open up the PDF by using a click event on a button. also there are multiple products mostly with different pdf's so i would need each link to be specific to the product.

Comment: I want to have everything connected to a MySql database as well to store the new and revised records. The purpose of this is to have this be used as a data entry tool where the user can add all info for the product and then have that products pdf linked to it for easy access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest way to do this: add a custom command to the Command Bar of the Data Grid Row for your Data Grid. In this example I'm calling the command Open PDF File. Then add this code to Execute code for the command:

```
partial void OpenPDFFile_Execute()
{
    const string LOCAL_SERVER_PDF_DIR = @"\\MyServer\PDFs\";
    const string WEB_SERVER_PDF_DIR = "http://myweb.server/PDFs/";
    const string PDF_SUFFIX = ".pdf"; //assumes you do not include the extension in the db field value

    if (AutomationFactory.IsAvailable)
    {
        //if the AutomationFactory is available, this is a desktop deployment
        //use the shell to open a PDF file from the local network
        dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Shell.Application");

        string filePath = LOCAL_SERVER_PDF_DIR + this.PDFFiles.SelectedItem.FileName + PDF_SUFFIX;
        shell.ShellExecute(filePath);
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise this must be a web deployment
        //in order to make this work you must add a reference to System.Windows.Browser
        //to the Client project of your LS solution
        var uri = new Uri(WEB_SERVER_PDF_DIR + this.PDFFiles.SelectedItem.FileName + PDF_SUFFIX);
        HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri, "_blank");
    }

}
```

You will need to add the following imports to the top of your user code file to make this code compile:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation;
using System.Windows.Browser;
```

I should mention that you need a directory to server the PDFs up from. This example is flexible with respect to deployment, because it handles both desktop and web configurations. Since you'll need to set up the PDF directoy, you may want to just handle one configuration option to simply things (or you could expose the same PDF directory over http and as a local network share).

You may also want to present this as a true link instead of a button. In order to do this, you'll need a custom SilverLight control. In any case, I would recommend implementing the PDF link using a button first. You can then move this same code to a link event handler as a separate project if that is worth spending time on.